# Creating Line-of-Business app with ASP.NET Core & Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, xaf

I want to create a Line-of-Business App in ASP.NET Core & (desirably) Razor Pages but have not managed to find a guide (or a starter project) that provides clear directives for how to handle complex CRUD functionality.

Given the following EF model:

```
public class Patient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string IDNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PatientCard> PatientCardsCollection { get; set; }
}

public class PatientCard
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CardNumber { get; set; }
    public Patient Patient { get; set; }
}
```

what I specifically haven't managed to find is how to create a ListView/DetailView for a **Patient** that has a collection of **PatientCard**s, which should be displayed in a DetailView for **Patient** and allow creation / editing / linking of **PatientCard**-s to **Patient**, as shown here: [Sample DetailView & nested ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtqMd.png) - in the screen Patient Business Object has a collection of PatientCard business objects.

Granted, this would likely require the utilization of some commercial components, like DevExtreme, Kendo, Syncfusion, etc. and we are ready to use any of those.

We have successfully used the DevExpress XAF framework with this purpose in the past, which creates stateful apps based on ASP.NET Forms and thus can not scale well. Here's a demo of what you can create in a matter of hours in it: https://demos.devexpress.com/XAF/MainDemo

We have also looked at other frameworks like the ASP.NET Zero ( https://aspnetzero.com ) and it seems promising but what we'd really like is to create this functionality from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I would split up the application logic and create a .NET Core MVC Application and a second project as .NET Core Web API (2).

So all database operations can be done using the Web Api and you can simply call the API in the MVC Application.

I'd advise you to use Angular, baselined into .NET Core MVC projects. This way your business applications provides a good user experience because it is a SPA.

You can put your backend engineers focused on a separate project => the web api and a team on the frontend/communication with the backend.

Hit me up if you have any questions!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong in that the difference between Angular and Razor is that "Razor renders the HTML on the server. Angular renders it on the client" but that doesn't answer my question of how to design views so that complex LoB CRUD functionality is achieved

Comment: What you do with the frontend is yours to choose, focus on Razor or use Angular predominantly. What you can do for the backend is implement the API in the same solution as that of your MVC app. If you work with serverside pages you do not really need a Web Api. So to implement the complex backend I'd have a look into Entity Framework and UnitOfWork-Repository pattern. I am a huge advocate of that combination.

Comment: I favor Razor over Angular at this point as it is easier for my C#-qualified team to adopt versus having to learn Angular & TypeScript/JavaScript.

Comment: if you have created an LoB solution using Angular or Razor, can you provide samples on how to create complex front-end with the model described above?

Answer (score 0):

The easy Solution would be a seperate list for the relation between Patient and PatientCard with it's own Detail.

Otherwise you can still implement your own logic in the Patient Detail to add, remove, edit patient cards. For example have a list with plus- and minus-button and field for the Card number on each row. You can achieve this using view component for the row. So every card you add is another "instance" of the **View Components**.  Like in this example of a TodoList:
[image]

Have a look here: [View Components Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1)